# node.js how to use a minified library used in client side

Tags: javascript, node.js

Basically, I am encoding a wav file using [libopus.js](https://github.com/kazuki/opus.js-sample) on the client side, now on the server side(node.js) I have to decode it using the same library, this is where I am getting lost, not sure how adapt the libopus.js for the server, to make things easier, it is present in minified form.

so what are the steps I have to follow to port a client side library to node.js.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment due to low reputation, the usual porting to node js usually means exposing the variable via exports instead of on the window, for example for the Opus which is defined in https://github.com/kazuki/opus.js-sample/blob/master/opus.js
you'd do exports.opus = Opus; and then in node you'd have:

var opus = require('./libopus').Opus and you will have that object.

However, from a fast glance it seems that it works with buffers etc which I am not sure how they port from browser to node js but give it a try I guess.

Comment: yes, that part I understand but [ libopus.js](https://github.com/kazuki/opus.js-sample/blob/master/libopus.js) is the one giving me the headache, unable to make head or tail about it.

Comment: Don't work with it, use the uncompiled code and build it your self, it's the result of all the other files combined.

p.s. it looks like it supports node structure (from the typeof  Module check at the beginning, but I never checked my self), there seems to be instructions on how to build it your self, you can fork it and in your package.json put your git resource instead of the name libopus and do your changes there.